# Counting up or down using a button click

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been trying to figure this counter out for a day or so. I am not very familiar with this as it has been several years since I've been to school and this is not my current job. I am doing this a a favor to my wife. I want it to count up when the next button is clicked and down if the back button is clicked.The buttons are created already and work. I just don't know how to integrate them into this function.

```
def question_count(self):

    a = len(question)
    b = 0

    # placing a question counter
    label1 = Label(gui, text=("Question:", b, "of", a),
                   width=15, bg="black", fg="blue")

    # place the label
    label1.place(x=0, y=50)
```

Comment: and where do you have these buttons? `Button` has option `command=self.question_count` (without `()`) to assign function. And when you click it then tkinter will use `()` to execute it.

Comment: if you want count between clicks then keep value in global or class variable. At this moment you have only local variables - and they will be destroyed when function will be  finished.

Comment: you could create Label at start (as class variable) and later only replace text - `self.label1["text"] = "new text"`. At this moment you will create new Label at every click and place it on top of previous `Label` - it will NOT remove previous label from memory. and tkinter will have to draw this label when you move/resize window (even if you don't see it).

Comment: The buttons are above this in they're own function. where would I put the command=self.question_count. and implement it?

Comment: you should put in button which have to execute it `Button(..., command=self.question_count)`

Comment: This is what I have with the buttons ----                                                           back_button = Button(gui, text="Back", command=self.back_btn,
                             width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", font=("ariel", 16, "bold"))

        back_button.place(x=210, y=380)

        next_button = Button(gui, text="Next", command=self.next_btn,
                             width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", font=("ariel", 16, "bold"))

        next_button.place(x=350, y=380)

Comment: maybe you should put this code directly  in `next_btn()` - or execute  `question_count()` in  `next_btn()`.

Comment: Frankly, when I look at this code - you should put it together with all `Button()` to display it at start, and `next_btn()` should only increase `b` and replace text in existing label. And `self.back_btn` should decrease `b` and also replace text in existing label.  But remember to use global variable `b` or class variable `self.b` to keep value between functions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! I ended up putting the counter inside the question function so it would increase and decrease as needed. Thank you for all your help!

def display_question(self):

```
    q_no = Label(gui, text=question[self.q_no], width=60, height=5,
                 font=('ariel', 16, 'bold'), anchor='w', justify='left', wraplength=600)
    # placing the option on the screen
    q_no.place(x=50, y=100)

    a = len(question)
    b = self.q_no + 1
    # placing a question counter
    label1 = Label(gui, text=("Question:", b, "of", a),
                   width=15, bg="white", fg="blue")

    # place the label
    label1.place(x=0, y=50)
```